# Using seaborn.boxplot() for unbalanced data frames

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, seaborn, boxplot

With the following code, I would like to create a box plot using `seaborn.boxplot()`.

```
print(result)
print(result.info())
sns.boxplot(y=result);
```

The output shows the following error:

```
             M1      M2
0       21846.0   49152
1         136.0    8192
2       21846.0      68
3         136.0  196608
4        1366.0   65536
...         ...     ...
141959      NaN  116736
141960      NaN      68
141961      NaN   29184
141962      NaN  116736
141963      NaN    8192

[141964 rows x 2 columns]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 141964 entries, 0 to 141963
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------   --------------   -----  
 0   3d-unet  113183 non-null  float64
 1   bert     141964 non-null  int64  
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 2.2 MB
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cta_dist.py", line 26, in <module>
    sns.boxplot(y=result);
  File "/home/u2/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/_decorators.py", line 46, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "/home/u2/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py", line 2240, in boxplot
    plotter = _BoxPlotter(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order,
  File "/home/u2/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py", line 406, in __init__
    self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order)
  File "/home/u2/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py", line 156, in establish_variables
    orient = infer_orient(
  File "/home/u2/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/_core.py", line 1305, in infer_orient
    y_type = None if y is None else variable_type(y)
  File "/home/u2/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/_core.py", line 1222, in variable_type
    if pd.isna(vector).all():
  File "/home/u2/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1442, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I guess that is because of unbalanced data points since M1 has less data values than M2. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: What is wrong with `sns.boxplot(data=result, orient='v')`? It is very very similar to your violinplot question.

Comment: Yes that works. I used `y=result`, but `data=result` fixes that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right you need to use the data-parameter for the whole dataframe. The y-parameter is just used for a dedicated variable stored in the dataframe:

```
print(result)
print(result.info())
sns.boxplot(y=result["M1"]);
```

Comment: That works if I separate the columns. So, instead of one figure with two bars, I have to create two figures each with one bar.